# Ubuntu Studio for ARM 64-bit devices (ie. Raspberry Pi, ODROID M1)

Tags: arm

I really like the Ubuntu Studio Linux distribution on AMD/Intel-based CPUs. However, I would like to run Ubuntu Studio on my ARM-based ODROID M1. Are there any plans to port Ubuntu Studio to ARM-based CPUs?

If not, what other similar Linux distributions would be good to use on an ODROID M1?

Comment: Hello this is a support site manned by volunteers nothing to do with making the products . No one here can answer that question, nor does it have anything to do with Ubuntu. Sorry.

Comment: Mate is working well for me on my Pi4.

Comment: Have you found any device arm64 supports ubuntu ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

- Install and run Ubuntu for ARM.
- Then

  ```
  $ sudo apt install tasksel
  $ sudo tasksel install ubuntustudio-desktop
  # OR
  $ sudo tasksel install ubuntustudio-desktop-core
  ```

More information [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-ubuntu-studio-desktop-environment-on-ubuntu-20-04).